# Launch Emacsclient with GUI (from Dock) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, automator, dock, emacsclient

How can I launch Emacsclient with GUI from the Dock (or maybe also from the terminal) on Mac OS X?

The EmacsWiki [describes](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS#toc20) how to create an "Emacs from Dock" app using Automator. It worked for me but I don't want to launch Emacs but Emacsclient. So, I tried replacing `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` with both `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient` and `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient -c` but both didn't work.

Comment: you might want to ask this question in emacs stackexchange if people do not reply here. Just saying.

Comment: if you're using the emacs-mac port, note that its `emacsclient` is a bit buggy: https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/issues/52

Answer (score 9):

#### From the terminal

You can find the appropriate path to `emacsclient` using `type` in your shell (assuming `emacsclient -c` works from said shell):

```
$ type emacsclient
emacsclient is /usr/local/bin/emacsclient
```

Then we can add the appropriate emacsclient flags (see `$ man emacsclient` for details) to open the GUI:

`/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -n -c -a ""`

#### From macOS GUI

To launch `emacsclient` from eg the Dock or Spotlight, it's easy to use Automator. Automator is built in to macOS.

Choose to make an "Application", then choose "Run Shell Script", and add a modified version of the above call to `emacsclient`:

`/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -n -c -a "" -- "$@"`

Then change "Pass input": use "as arguments" instead of "to stdin".

The added `"$@"` is where any optional arguments passed to this shell script will be placed. Here, this allows you to pass a filename to open with `emacsclient`. Automator automates passing this filename in when, eg, you click to open a file with the application we've just made. This also allows you to set the application to be the default application for certain file types.

#### From anywhere, flexibly

Another way to run the above shell command is with [`skhd` (link)](https://github.com/koekeishiya/skhd). `skhd` is far more involved to learn, but ultimately makes it much easier to set up a large number of shell commands with rapid access.

For example, you could make "Ctrl-o" from anywhere in macOS enter a mode you name `open_app`, from which you could press "e" to open `emacsclient`, "d" to open `emacs --debug-init`, "t" to run `emacs --adv-timers`, "f" to open Firefox, "F" to open a second Firefox profile, etc.

Comment: The khd link is dead, now.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to create an applescript that does whatever the original poster desires, and wrap it up in an application using something like platypus or automator.  See https://superuser.com/questions/685111/basic-setup-of-emacs-server-under-osx for additional ideas such as using the `--daemon` command-line argument instead of placing `(server-start)` within the user-configuration file.

Here is an example applescript:

```
#  (server-start) must be inside `init.el` or `.emacs` file.
#
#  This script can also be used in the terimal:  osascript path-to-script arguments
#  Terminal Example:
#  osascript /absolute/path/to/applescript/file "-e '(progn (dired \"/Applications\") (message \"Hello-World\!\"))'"

on run argv
    set arg to item 1 of argv
    set emacs to application "Emacs"
    set appIsRunning to emacs is running
    if appIsRunning then
        say "Emacs is already running."
        do shell script "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient " & arg
    else
    tell application "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs" to activate
        say "Please wait five seconds for Emacs to load."
        delay 5
        do shell script "/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient " & arg
    end if
end run
```